Could someone explain to me why my approach here is wrong?
The area of the central maximum produced by a circular aperture is $8.25*10^{-6}$ m$^{2}$. If the aperture is 1.2 mm in diameter and the screen is 3 m away from the slit, what is the wavelength of the light?
Here is what I did:
First we see that it's a circular aperture so we have: $\theta =\frac{1.22\lambda}{D} $, rearranged to be  $ \lambda =\frac{\theta D}{1.22}$.
Then I made a triangle with the base being $L$ and the height being $r$ of the central maximum. This gave me $\theta =\frac{r}{L}$, no tan$^{-1}$  because of small angle approximation.
Given the area of the central maximum I set up $r = \sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}}$ and got $r = 1.62*10^{-3}$m.
I then plugged the $r = 1.62*10^{-3}$m into $\theta =\frac{r}{L}$ which got me $\theta = \frac{1.62*10^{-3}}{3}$ = $5.4*10^{-4}$ rads.
I then went back to  $ \lambda =\frac{\theta D}{1.22}$ and plugged in the values, $\lambda = \frac{5.4*10^{-4}*1.2*10^{-3}}{1.22}$ = $5.31*10^{-7}$m, but the answers are only in nm, and the answer is 531 nm.
I saw the professor work it out and they had $y = \frac{1.22\lambda L}{a}$ and had $A = \pi r^{2} = \pi y^{2}$ and solved for $\lambda$ via $8.25*10^{-6} = \pi \frac{1.22^{2}\lambda^{2}3^{2}}{(1.2*10^{-3})^{2}} $.
Did they get $y = \frac{1.22\lambda L}{a}$ because they substituted the $\theta$ with $\frac{L}{r}$? I was only given $\theta =\frac{1.22\lambda}{D} $ on my formula sheet. If this is the case, why isn't it $\frac{r}{L}$? I setup a right triangle with $\theta$ at the bottom left of a right triangle where the height of the triangle is on the right side, the base is on the bottom, and the hypotenuse runs from the top right to the bottom left. I also don't understand what $y$ is in this problem, and why they were able to have $A = \pi r^{2} = \pi y^{2}$.

Read the answer here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Read the answer here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic

Stop asking "check my work" questions.

Please at least define your variables and include a diagram if possible. It's frustrating trying to decipher what you mean without them.

The term $y$ in the Professors' calculation seems to be the radius $r$. They are simply using a different symbol for the radius.
Now $\theta = \frac{y}{L}$
Also the professor is using a different symbol for the diameter of the aperture. The professor's $a$ is the $D$ in your formula.
